# rails associations new method belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user model which has a program. I want to add a program according to the current user.

What is wrong with my code?

```
def new
  @program = Program.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @program }
  end
end

# POST /programs
# POST /programs.json
def create
  @program = current_user.build_program(params[:program])

  if @program.save
    if request.xhr?
      #do nothing
    else
      redirect_to @program, notice: 'User was successfully created.'
    end
  else
    if request.xhr?
      render :status => 403
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

Additionaly, when a post request is sent I see the post requests in the console as:

```
Started POST "/programs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-12 17:42:46 +0300
Processing by ProgramController#index as */*
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"m21h2SRHJ1A9TlKVIdwZOwodKx+vPEx16dd5z936LmY=", "program"=>{"title"=>"baslik", "details"=>"deneme"}}
```

But this tuple doesn't get added to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to instantiate a new object on a `belongs_to` association you have to use [`build_*`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-build_association). So, instead of:

```
@program = current_user.program.new(params[:program])
```

do:

```
@program = current_user.build_program(params[:program])
```

If you do this, you don't have to set the foreign key explicitly anymore. You can delete the following line:

```
@program.user_id = current_user.id
```

You can also use this concept in `def new`:

```
@program = current_user.build_program
```

Comment: What happens if I use @program = Program.new(params[:program].merge(:user_id => current_user.id )) in create?

Comment: The same as when you use `current_user.build_program(params[:program])`.

Comment: Thank you. But there is still a problem with adding it to the DB. I've edited the question.

Comment: Yes, I do.  attr_accessible :details, :title, :user_id

Comment: @Yagiz Do you have your routes set up correctly? It looks like the post is handled by the index action, not by create. `Processing by ProgramController#index as */*` Check and/or post config/routes.rb please.

Comment: how can I add a POST resource to programs/ ? There is a   match "programs/" => 'program#index', as: 'programs' to get all of the programs, but I want to add a POST request route also.

Comment: Instead of that, you'd better use `resources :programs` to get the standard routes for all the basic actions (`index`, `show`, `new`, `create`, `edit`, `update` and `destroy`). See [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for details.

Comment: I've added   match "programs/" => 'program#index', as: 'programs', :via => :get and match "programs/" =>'program#create', :via => :post,

Comment: But after I submit the button, it gives an error : "ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template program/create, application/create with "

Comment: @Yagiz, this new error means that a redirect or render doesn't happen in create and therefor Rails looks for a template, which doesn't exist. Please try to debug what goes wrong exactly.